# How to implement promises in Cordova plugin JS interface?

Tags: javascript, cordova, promise, cordova-plugins

Below is the JS interface skeleton I build for my cordova plugin. I am new to Javascript and would like to implement promises. How can I do this?

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

module.exports = {
  methodA : function(initData, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      exec(successCallback,
           failureCallback,
           "MyPlugin",
           "methodA",
           [initData]);
  },
  methodB : function(successCallback) {
      exec(successCallback,
           null,
           "MyPlugin",
           "methodB",
           []);
  },
  methodC : function(key, data, successCallback, failureCallback) {
       exec(successCallback,
            failureCallback,
            "MyPlugin",
            "methodC",
            [key, data]);
  },
  methodD : function(key, successCallback, failureCallback) {
       exec(successCallback,
            failureCallback,
            "MyPlugin",
            "methodD",
            [key]);
  }
};
```

Comment: what exactly you intend to implement in promise? Be more specific so that it will be helpful for easy understanding

Comment: instead of callbacks - success and failure, I want to use Promises. The user while using my plugin should expect a promise instead of callbacks.

Comment: Dont use promise jus as a callback aggregation until you really need to, Check out this link on the same - https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970